# How to access helpers in controller and why is my find() empty?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor

I'm pretty new to the new meteor 1.3.1. So I've never worked with helpers before.

This is my helper:

```
this.helpers({
    questions() {
        return Questions.find({categoryId: this.categoryId});
    }
});
```

First question: How do I access this helper (`questions`) within it's own controller? I tried `$scope.questions`, `this.questions` and `this.play.questions` (`play` is the alias of the controller). Everything is `undefined`.
In my view I iterate with `ng-repeat='question in play.questions'` and it works fine.

Then I thought maybe helpers can't be accessed in the controller. So I tried this:
`this.questions = Questions.find({categoryId: this.categoryId});`

But here the problem is that I get an empty cursor. Any idea why that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are in your controller function and you have used

```
$reactive(this).attach($scope)
```

before you do

```
this.questions = Questions.find({category: this.categoryId});
```

? One reason your cursor is empty when not using a helper might be that your subscription is not ready by the time you set `this.questions`. Therefore you should make this assignment reactive by wrapping it inside a [`this.autorun`](https://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.6/autorun). By doing this the cursor gets updated as soon as your client side collection is populated.

I think instead of calling your helper from within your controller you should extract a common function and use it inside the helper and whereever else you need it. The helpers are really only used to get data to the UI if I am not mistaken (<- ?).

Comment: Almost satisfying. `this.autorun` helped me to fetch data without helpers. And I think you're right with that helpers are only for UI. Thanks.

Comment: @Fabic But I still didn't get how to operate with these cursor in controller? Will you please give me an example , how to iterate over cursor in controller?

Comment: @Priyanka You simply do `this.questions.forEach(function(item){     //process item })`. Or you do `this.questions.fetch()` what gives you an array which you can iterate as usual.

Comment: @Fabic Thank you.. :)